# How capture the memory utilization of DBT run model

Tags: dbt

Original Problem is :

I'm running dbt (5 models) in GCP (k8s engine) with minimal record count as 500 Records with some business logic and load the records from one dataset of table to another dataset of table (GBQ) but it consume more memory approx. 2GB. Execute the same models in laptop, it occupy 5GB of ram out of 8GB. Even same memory occupy second time execution without recompile (No changes in the DBT Models).

Comment: what machine's memory utilization are you interested in? are you interested in size of data on disk in GBQ? or the RAM usage of your local machine?

Comment: what do you mean by "execute the same models in laptop"?

Comment: @AndersSwanson- Here i'm looking the memory utilization is RAM Usage in local machine. And Same model means which model used for execution in laptop and K8s.